# do you know any javascript api with many premise handling? like in artificial intelligence

Tags: javascript, jquery, artificial-intelligence

JQuery can handle events implementing Observer Design Pattern, but it can handle only one event for one callback function

I was wondering, if it could handle many events: when all this events was triggered, or when all boolean premises became true then call a function

It would be much better to develop dynamic applications

Do you know if already exist something like that?
If not: do you think it would be nice if i develop?

EDIT:
i would like to do something like this:

```
when((a==b && c!=0), function(){ 
//do something when a==b and c!=0
alert("a==b && c!=0");
});
```

EDIT 2:

I've found a great API that allow listen for variable changes. You just have to do something like this:

```
obj.watch(function(){
alert("obj changes");
});
```

http://watch.k6.com.br/

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe this'll help more?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this manually:

```
var flag1 = false;
var flag2 = false;
var flag3 = false;
var checkAllFlags = function () {
    if (!flag1 || !flag2 || !flag3) return;
    checkAllFlags = function () { };
    allFlagsSet();
}
var allFlagsSet = function () {
    // Execute here when all flags are set
}

// When you set a flag do it like this:
flag2 = true;
checkAllFlags();
```

Or you could use this class:

```
window.flagger = function (count, callback, once) {
    var curr = this;
    curr.callback = callback;
    if (once)
        curr.called = false;
    curr.flags = [];
    curr.flagsLeft = count;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        curr.flags[i] = false;

    this.flag = function (index) {
        if (!curr.flags[index]) {
            curr.flags[index] = true;
            if (--curr.flagsLeft <= 0 && (!once || !curr.called)) {
                if (once) curr.called = true;
                curr.callback();
            }
        }
    };
    this.unflag = function (index) {
        if (curr.flags[index]) {
            curr.flags[index] = false;
            curr.flagsLeft++;
        }
    };
    this.reset = function (force) {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            curr.flags[i] = false;
        curr.flagsLeft = count;
        if (once && force)
            curr.called = false;
    };
    this.isFlagged = function (index) {
        return curr.flags[index];
    };
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var myFlagger = new flagger(
    /* The amount of flags that need to be set: */8,
    /* The function that needs to be called when the flags are all set: */
    function () { alert('Callback function called'); },
    /* If the callback function should be called again when a flag is unflagged and reflagged.
       Optional. Default: false */false);

// You can now use these functions:
myFlagger.flag(0); // Use this to set a flag, index ranges from 0 to count - 1.
myFlagger.unflag(0); // Unflags an index.
myFlagger.reset(); // Resets all flags to false.
myFlagger.reset(true); // Using this forces the reset, returning to full start
                       // state, causes callback function to be called again
                       // even if 'once' is specified.
alert('0 is flagged: ' + myFlagger.isFlagged(1)); // Returns if flag is flagged.
```

I hope this somewhat helps you.

Comment: but then I will have to verify all variables when a variable value change.
I was wondering something more like one observer for each variable in premise, when the subject value change then verify the others premises if all true then call the callback function

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature within jQuery, sorry :/

Comment: @user858257 the logic could also be performed using binary flags and bitmasks, but I'm not sure it would be any easier.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Example:_Flags_and_bitmasks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_%28programming%29)s to me. Most of the libraries developed with that concept (there are many for JavaScript, including jQuery.deferred) can simply build a new Promise for the event that some others got fulfilled.

Comment: I am reading $.deffered and it is really helpfull, with some work it could be what I am looking for, thank you

Comment: I'm think jQuery's promise class is not the most powerful, but if you already use jQuery it might be an alternative to dojo or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: actually, the promise and deferreds classes of jquery isnt that cool! I dont found a way to use the $.when when something of my application logic happen, just when something of jquery api happen like $ajax.

Comment: You can create your own [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) in your application logic. Calling $.when on them should do the task. But as I said, jQuery isn't the most powerful or best-documented promise library.